# listing the source directories for gdb in .emacs

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am running gdb from inside emacs and am looking for an automatic way to specify the source directories in my .emacs file. Basically, it is becoming a pain to always specify the source file directories for gdb :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize GUD GDB's command-line. Unfortunately, this is a global setting, and not something per-buffer/-project…

```
  M-x customize-apropos gud
```

(or navigate to Customize group **Emacs/Programming/Tools/Gud**)

Look for **Gud Gdb Command Name** and set it to something like

```
  gdb --annotate=3 -d /usr/src/whatever -d ~/more/src
```

(The `--annotate=3` is required for GUD to work properly.)

Comment: This is working out nicely for me. Also, when I save, it adds to the .emacs file.